# magento1 migrate to multiple magento 2 stores

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration-tool

Anyone knows what happen for all the migrate changes tables in m1, if I want to start migration to a new m2 store.

E.g. I migrated m1 data to the first m2 store and all the deltalog tables (with prefix m2_cl_*) and triggers (for tracking changes) have been created in the M1. Now I want m1 data to migrate to an another m2 store. What will happen will all the deltalog tables and triggers. Will they be dropped and recreated? I use Magento data migration tool.